# how come this $\frac {\partial \hat y} {\partial W^{(2)}}$ in derivative

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

I have the following function:
$$
\frac {\partial J}{\partial W^{(2)}} = \sum \frac {\partial \left( \frac {1}{2}(y-\hat y)^2 \right)} {\partial W^{(2)}}
$$

Unlike $\hat y$ which depends on $W^{(2)}$, $y$ is constant. So,$\frac {\partial y} {\partial W^{(2)}} = 0$ and we have the following:

$$
\frac {\partial J}{\partial W^{(2)}} = - \sum (y-\hat y) \frac {\partial \hat y} {\partial W^{(2)}}
$$

Could you please explain how come this part of function $\frac {\partial \hat y} {\partial W^{(2)}}$?

Comment: figured it out, it is because [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule)